# JavaScript regex, exclude hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

How do I create a regex pattern to match the follwing in mongoDB

```
1985010203-1234
```

I would like to match on these different alterantives

```
1985010203-1
198501020312
85010203-1
8501020312
010203-1234
0102931234
```

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: Very good site for learning basics of RegEx: https://regexone.com/, then you can test your RegEx in https://regex101.com/. When you have a working RegEx you can post it here and ask for help

Comment: Looks like `\d+-?\d+` to me.

Answer (score 0):

How about it?

```js
console.log("1985010203-1234".match(/\d+(-\d+)?/));
```

Comment: What if I want to add only allow numbers 0-9?